New Problem with Ubuntu Subiquity Auto-install
I've been automating installations of Ubuntu server with cloud-config for a while but when I try to supply my file (or even a simpler file) in 24.04. I get the following message.
Error parsing preconfiguration file: Syntax error: unable to determine template owner
I can't seem to find anything useful about this online. Has anyone here encountered this before?

This looks like possibly a bug in subiquity, the auto-installer. Could you report a bug on launchpad please?
